# securing admin panel - ASP.NET using SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq, security, entity-framework-4

I have a ecommerce system that i wrote by myself.
I have a table "admin_table" in this table i store admin username and admin password.
I use this system only for myself - but i want it to be super secure - will it be better to set username and password hardcoded-inside the code or to keep with the current method? what will be the best way to secure it?

Comment: You know, if the attacker gets the access to your db (or file system on the server), you're done either way :) Encryption etc works just as a slowing mechanism, but it won't give you super-uber-protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be **super secure**, I think both way will not do what you expect.

Because hard-code in your code means, anyone who read the code can obtain your *password*.

Saving the password as a database field is again not a very good way in terms of security.

If you can save the password in a `encrypted` manner or use something like `membership provider` which do the encryption for you.

You might need to look at [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and 
[Create a Custom Membership Provider](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)

Comment: what kind of encrypted manner\membership provider you recommend?